# ZF3 route locale parameter

Tags: zend-framework3

I have a translation in my project for templates and routes. when the locale is set, the translations are working except the locale parameter in the links is not correct.
my default language is NL. so I have a page `www.website.com/nl/contact`
when I switch to language fr I go to `www.website.com/fr/contact`, then when I go to look in the HTML source, the link is again www.website.com/nl/contact in stead of `www.website.com/fr/contact` so the locale parameter in the links is not updated regarding the setLocale

my module.php

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $eventManager->attach(
        \Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR,
        function ($e) {
            $application    = $e->getApplication();
            $match          = $application->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();

            if (null === $match) {
                $params     = [
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'not-found',
                    // Here you can add common params for your application routes
                ];

                $viewModel = $e->getViewModel();
                $viewModel->setTemplate('layout/website');

                $routeMatch = new RouteMatch($params);

                $routeMatch->setMatchedRouteName('home');
                $application->getMvcEvent()->setRouteMatch(
                    $routeMatch
                );
            }
        }
    );

    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();

    if (!$e->getRequest() instanceof ConsoleRequest) {

        $this->setLanguage($e);
        $eventManager->attach('route', array($this, 'onPreRoute'), 100);
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $this->initAcls($e);

        if (isset($_SERVER['APP_ENV']) and $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] == 'production') {
            $eventManager->attach('finish', array($this, 'outputCompress'), 100);
        }
    }
}

private function setLanguage($e)
{
    $redirectBase   = $e->getRequest()->getServer()->get('REDIRECT_BASE');
    $requestUri = $e->getRequest()->getServer()->get('REQUEST_URI');

    $cmsString      = substr($requestUri, strlen($redirectBase), 4);
    $language = 'nl';
    $routeTranslation = true;

    if ($requestUri != '/') {
        $language = substr($requestUri, 1, 2);
    }

    if ($cmsString == 'cms/') {
        $language = 'en-us';
        $routeTranslation = false;
    }

    $translator = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('MvcTranslator');
    $translator->setLocale($language);

    if ($routeTranslation) {
        $translator->addTranslationFile('PhpArray', __DIR__.'/../language/Routes/' . $language . '.php', 'default', $language);
    }
}

public function onPreRoute($e)
{
    $app = $e->getTarget();
    $serviceManager = $app->getServiceManager();
    $serviceManager->get('router')->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('MvcTranslator'));
}
```